# WebGL drawBuffer outputs black textures

Tags: javascript, webgl, framebuffer, multipass

I am trying to write simple webgl multipass program with the help of drawBuffers. I create 2 drawBuffer textures and assign color to them in fragmentShaderPass1. Texture1 should be green and Texture2 should be brown. Then I pass these textures as a uniform to fragmentShaderPass2 which uses color of the Texture1 to render rectangle. Problem is that rectangle is always black instead of green! What am I doing wrong here?

```
    // STAGE 1
    let fragmentShaderPass1 = `
        #extension GL_EXT_draw_buffers : require
        precision highp float;
        precision highp int;
        precision highp sampler2D;

        void main( void )
        {
            gl_FragData[0] = vec4(.2, .8, .0, 1);  // green
            gl_FragData[1] = vec4(.6, .5, .4, .3);  // brown
        }
    `;
    let pass1_prog = createProgram(gl, globals.vertexShader, fragmentShaderPass1);

    let firstStageFrameBuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, firstStageFrameBuffer);

    gl.useProgram(pass1_prog);

    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
    {
        let tex = gl.createTexture();
        textures.push(tex);

        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);

        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, canvas.width, canvas.height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);

        // attach texture to framebuffer
        gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, ext.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_WEBGL + i, gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex, 0);
    }

    gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST); // framebuffer doesn't even have a depth buffer!
    gl.viewport(0, 0, _this.canvas.width, _this.canvas.height); 

    ext.drawBuffersWEBGL([
        ext.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_WEBGL,
        ext.COLOR_ATTACHMENT1_WEBGL
    ]);

    gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1); 



    // STAGE 2
    let fragmentShaderPass2 = `
        precision highp float;
        precision highp int;
        precision highp sampler2D;

        uniform sampler2D inColor0;
        uniform sampler2D inColor1;

        void main( void )
        {
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(inColor0, vec2(0.5));
        }
    `;
    let pass2_prog = createProgram(gl, globals.vertexShader, fragmentShaderPass2);

    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);

    gl.useProgram(pass2_prog);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 
    gl.clearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(pass2_prog, "inColor0"), 0);

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, textures[1]); 
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(pass2_prog, "inColor1"), 1);

    gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
```

Comment: Why do you use `FLOAT` type for `texImage2D`? Shouldn't it be in your case `UNSIGNED_BYTE`?

Comment: @vHawk you are right. I changed to UNSIGNED_BYTE. The example still not working though.

Comment: how does your vertex shader look?

Comment: for the code posted you should see errors in the Javascriot console. Did you look at the JavaScript console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you posted above does not make your textures renderable and gets this error in [the JavaScript console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/)

> RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It might be non-power-of-2 or have incompatible texture filtering (maybe)?

They are not renderable because they have no mips but are set to use mips (the default). They are also probably not power of 2 dimensions though you didn't show the size of the canvas but just guessing it's not a power of 2.

Making them renderable

```
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

makes them render

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const _this = {canvas};
const textures = [];
const gl = _this.canvas.getContext('webgl');
const ext = gl.getExtension('WEBGL_draw_buffers');
if (!ext) { alert('need WEBGL_draw_buffers'); }
const globals = {
  vertexShader: `
    void main() {
      gl_Position = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
      gl_PointSize = 100.0;
    }
  `,
}
// STAGE 1
let fragmentShaderPass1 = `
  #extension GL_EXT_draw_buffers : require
  precision highp float;
  precision highp int;
  precision highp sampler2D;

  void main( void )
  {
      gl_FragData[0] = vec4(.2, .8, .0, 1);  // green
      gl_FragData[1] = vec4(.6, .5, .4, 1);  // brown
  }
`;
let pass1_prog = createProgram(gl, globals.vertexShader, fragmentShaderPass1);

let firstStageFrameBuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, firstStageFrameBuffer);

gl.useProgram(pass1_prog);

for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  let tex = gl.createTexture();
  textures.push(tex);

  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);

  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, canvas.width, canvas.height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

  // attach texture to framebuffer
  gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, ext.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_WEBGL + i, gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex, 0);
}

gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST); // framebuffer doesn't even have a depth buffer!
gl.viewport(0, 0, _this.canvas.width, _this.canvas.height);

ext.drawBuffersWEBGL([
  ext.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_WEBGL,
  ext.COLOR_ATTACHMENT1_WEBGL
]);

gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);



// STAGE 2
let fragmentShaderPass2 = `
        precision highp float;
        precision highp int;
        precision highp sampler2D;

        uniform sampler2D inColor0;
        uniform sampler2D inColor1;

        void main( void )
        {
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(inColor0, vec2(0.5));
        }
    `;
let pass2_prog = createProgram(gl, globals.vertexShader, fragmentShaderPass2);

gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);

gl.useProgram(pass2_prog);
gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
gl.clearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(pass2_prog, "inColor0"), 0);

gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, textures[1]);
gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(pass2_prog, "inColor1"), 1);

gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);


// ---
function createProgram(gl, vSrc, fSrc) {
  return twgl.createProgram(gl, [vSrc, fSrc]);
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Note I changed the "brown" color from `vec4(.6, .5, .4, .3)` to `vec4(.6, .5, .4, 1)`.  `vec4(.6, .5, .4, .3)` is an invalid color for the canvas unless you do more math on output or set the canvas to not except premultiplied alpha color. Your output shader didn't do any extra math and you didn't show your code for setting up the canvas. The default is the browser expects you to put premultiplied color values in the canvas. `vec4(.6, .5, .4, .3)` is not premultiplied alpha because if it was r, g, and b could not be > a.

Comment: How can I known whether Texture is renderable? I draw with texture TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER has set, but TEXTURE_WRAP_S, TEXTURE_WRAP_T has not set. Not any warning at console, but render result keep black.  If I  follow you way, set then all, render success. I have searched about TEXTURE_WRAP_S,TEXTURE_WRAP_T, but cannot see any info that not set then will cause render not work. This is the code  : https://gist.github.com/joshuafc/2b224e5549239a327d4333236c96b427